# Best way to handle objects property:value in the stdin in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, sh

Bonjour,

I launch `nslookup someServer`.  I consider I get a serie of object (as in powers hell) separated by empty lines and not simply a stdout.

```
$ nslookup someServer
Server:      10.0.0.1
Address:     10.0.0.1#53

Name: someServer
Address: 10.0.0.5

$
```

How to get the object who have both properties Name and Address?

```
nslookup someServer | haveboth Name Address | wc -l
```

Does it exists in GNU utilities?

Answer (score 0):

are you simply looking for a way to check that you have both of these values in your output?

Then you could use perl in oneline mode (probably not the most pretty solution imaginable, but does what you want and could be expanded to check more things easily)

```
nslookup someServer | perl -ne '$v{"NAME"}++ if /Name/; $v{"ADDRESS"}++ if /Address/; END{ print "Has both values\n" if $v{"NAME"} && $v{"ADDRESS"} }'
```

this goes through your output and counts the occurrences of `Name` and `Address` and then prints a message if it has more than zero of both.

If using perl in this way is a viable option, then I can recommend this page for further reading on [perl oneliners](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_top_10_tricks_of)

EDIT: 
in case you want to have access to the values that are stored in your `property:` you can use

```
nslookup someServer | perl -F: -lane '$v{"NAME"} = $F[1] if /Name/; $v{"ADDRESS"} = $F[1] if /Address/; END{ print $v{"ADDRESS"}." ".$v{"NAME"} if exists $v{"ADDRESS"} && $v{"NAME"} }'
```

This will split a given line on `:` as field separator and store the value in the variable instead of simple counting occurrences. Note that done in this way it would only store the last occurrence.